# How can I make my application as home application

Tags: android

I have a wizard application that I want to make Home application. How can I convert regular application into a home application.

Comment: What do you mean by "Home application"? Do you really mean default application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491428/changing-the-user-interface-of-an-android

Answer (score 2):

Simply by adding this line in your manifest!

```
 <activity android:name="Home"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Should work :-p